# how to create XML Doc in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, gdata

in my current project i need to create one xml file and send it to server.

i searched many sites a got information about some API like
NSXML (now its deprecated)
http://onlinefreecomputertutorials.blogspot.in/2011/07/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents.html
GDATAXML (now its deprecated)
http://www.raywenderlich.com/725/how-to-read-and-write-xml-documents-with-gdataxml

please if is there any API i can use to create xml or you have any idea just share with me or any link for tutorial to create xml in objective c.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Use [TCMXMLWriter](https://github.com/monkeydom/TCMXMLWriter). It's a small XML library with a very nice syntax.

Comment: many thanks for this but i am new to objective c also so can you please tell me how to use this library, any tutorial or example will be helpful for me, i want to try right now.

Comment: @RDC Have you actually taken the time to look at the link to the answer? There's an example there and documentation too. You can't expect people to do ALL of your work for you.

Comment: @NickBull i have downloaded and tried in my project but still it generating errors as i have already got for GDATAXML library, so i asked about any full example btw thanks for giving your time.

Comment: You find a full example in the demo project which is included. Post the results to your server using NSMutableURLRequest.